# PostgreSQL creating table with Python failed

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

For some unknown reason table in database was not created. How to solve it?

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', host='localhost', password='123456')
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE example;')
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE HARMKA
                         (ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                         PHARMACY_LICENSE CHAR(100),
                         STREET CHAR(150),
                         CITY CHAR(30));""")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO HARMKA VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (1, '12345', 'street', 'Denwer'))
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: If you'd tell us what went wrong, what error you received or what exactly you mean by "failed".. I mean that would be just nifty...

Comment: There is no error. Database is created, but table is not in Database.

Comment: What if you also commit the transactions? `conn.commit()`

Comment: Adelin I think conn.autocommit = True is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect to `example` database and then create tables and manipulate data.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='example', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='123456')
```

Comment: import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', host='localhost', password='123456')
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE example;')
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = 'example', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='123456')
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()

Comment: @FootAdministration glad it helped!